# React Native Reanimated not working in React Native web and throwing module could not parse error when using webpack to run web build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, react-native-web, react-native-reanimated

I have existing React-Native app in typescript. In that we are using React-native-reanimated 2.14.4. According to documentation this version has support for web and I have done the configuration as mentioned in official docs.

I am using webpack.config.js to launch my app and also I have babel.config.js. In babel.config.js I added required plugin

But when I run my app from webpack it throws error. I am attaching configuration screenshots for reference.
Do I need to anything else in webpack aslo? or any idea how it could be resolved

[image: package.json] [image: babel.config.js file]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any one any idea?

Comment: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/web-support/. So I am at the point where ranimate works in ios/android but does not work in web. I am working in expo and do not clearly understand how to modify the webpack.config file. Although my link gives vague instructions. Have you made any progress? My current situation is that the application loads well in web development server but the animations do not fire.

Answer (score -1):

react-native-reanimated I believe is a mobile only module so you don't really want it to compile with the web bundle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @trainee_jc Your statement is incorrect. reanimate has supported web since v2 as seen here. https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/web-support/