# Trouble running Reanimated 2 or 3 on both Web/Expo React Native

Tags: next.js, expo, cross-platform, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I’m building a universal app using React Native that runs on Next.js/Expo for web/mobile and currently, version 2.14.4 works on mobile but errors out on web and 3.4.2 works on web but errors out in Expo.

We are likely going with the old architecture since Expo doesn’t fully support the new architecture yet, so based on that which version of Reanimated do you suggest we invest time in getting to work?
Here’s the error we get when trying to run react-native-reanimated v2.14.4 on web (this question was asked before with no answer: [React Native Reanimated not working in React Native web and throwing module could not parse error when using webpack to run web build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76298836/react-native-reanimated-not-working-in-react-native-web-and-throwing-module-coul)):

[image]

And if we upgrade react-native-reanimated to 3.4.2 the error above on web disappears and we get this error on Expo Go:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late to help you now, but I just had the same problem as your last error (*Mismatch between Javacript part and native part of Reanimated*). I'll leave my solution here for whoever needs it in the future.

What finally fixed it for me was running this command.

```
yarn react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

It must have resetted some cache that got stuck or something. It's worth a try if you have the same problem.